# Javascript overloaded parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to merge objects and functions in javascript. Currently I have such code:

```
var Functor = function(f, prop) {
  var inst = function() {return inst.__op__.apply(this, arguments)}
  inst.__op__ = f
  for (var key in prop)
    inst[key] = prop[key]
  return inst
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
var x = Functor(function(arg) {console.log(arg)}, {qwe:123})
console.log(x.qwe) // 123
x(321) // 321
```

But I have two problems: firstly, I don't like copying properties from `prop` argument to returned `inst`, I'd like there to be some kind of link to `prop`. Secondly, I want to be able to adress `this` in first `Functor` argument getting link to the `inst`. It seems that my problems can be solved reshaping `Functor` function for using with `new` keyword. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Important features are that I'm able to change `__op__` property (which is kind of `()` operator) and that I can bind the result and get correct behaviour:

```
var x = Functor()
x.__op__ = console.log
var echo = x.bind(console)
echo(123) // 123
```

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with any of my problems.
Here's a fiddle with code copied there: http://jsfiddle.net/avmhbyzr/

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're really asking here?  Maybe if you described the higher level problem you were trying to solve, we'd have a better idea what to suggest that is different than what you're already doing.  You may also want to read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because that seems to be what you're doing (describing a problem with your attempted solution rather than describing the actual problem you're trying to solve).

Comment: I'm all for answering the X question (even if there is a Y) .. but I do agree that more of a context would make the 'question' / 'problem' more apparent. E.g. why *are* the properties copied? Why *is* the `__op__` property used instead of closing over `f` directly? Why is the `this` of the returned closure used in the `apply`?

Comment: @user2864740 There's no higher level problem yet, I just want to be able to do it. 1) I copy properties because I don't know how else to make returned value have those properties. That is my problem one. 2) I use `__op__` because I want to be able to change what `()` do on my value, that is shown in the last example. 3) I use `this` there so that `call, bind, apply` called on my value were bound to `this` of `()` operator (example with `console.log`, which doesn't work unless bound to `console`).

Comment: @jfriend00 I would say that my goal is to have such method: having arbitrary object `A`, I want to extend it with additional property called `__op__`, which would work as a `()` operator on that object. Right now it would be done as `var B = Functor(operator, A)`. But my approach has flaws, so I look for a better way.

Comment: The first example doesn't use `{qwe:..}` (the props) when `x` is invoked. I'm still not sure how they are to be used.

Comment: @user2864740 1) It doesn't, because I don't know how to. That is my second problem, getting `this` inside `__op__` to be link to the value until it is bound to something else. 2) Tell me your browser version, in all my browsers it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid copying over all the properties from `prop`, you can set `prop` as the prototype of `inst`. Since `inst` is a function (not an ordinary object), you have no control of its constructor (it has to be `Function`), so the only way to change its prototype is via the internal `__proto__` property.

The immediate drawback is, you lose access to all methods of a function, e.g. you cannot call x.call(). But you can solve it by chaining Function.prototype to prop. See the code below.

```
var Functor = function(f, prop) {
  var inst = function() {
      return inst.__op__.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  // Setup prototype chain: inst -> prop -> Function.prototype
  prop.__proto__ = inst.__proto__
  inst.__proto__ = prop

  inst.__op__ = f
  return inst
}

!function() {
    var x = Functor(null, {qwe:123})
    console.log(x.qwe) // 123

    // Method 1: bind the context to __op__
    x.__op__ = console.log.bind(console)
    x(321) // 321

    // Method 2: call x with the context
    x.__op__ = console.log
    x.call(console, 321) // 321
}()
```

As for the use of `this`, you are already correctly passing on the context to `__op__` at `inst` via `Function.prototype.apply`.

The way to pass on a context is via calling `x` with a context (Method 2), or the more clumsy `console.x = x; console.x(321)`. If you don't want to do this, you can always bind the context into `__op__` (Method 1).

Keep in mind that when a function is executed, it needs both the context (`this`) and the arguments. The context is either permanently bound to the function (Method 1) or supplied in situ (Method 2).

Comment: I had this idea: `prop.__proto__ = inst.__proto__`. And the problem is, I don't want to modify `prop` object so seriously, in a way that it loses part of it's properties. I quite wanted the opposite: to have full access to its contents. Multiple inheritance would help, but unfortunately there isn't one. As for `this` problem, both those methods are not quite what I wanted. This one `x.__op__ = console.log.bind(console)` I'd prefer to see as `x.__op__ = console.log; x = x.bind(console)`, so that `x` works exactly as a function put into `__op__`.

Comment: This definition of `Functor` already works with this piece of code: `x.__op__ = console.log; echo = x.bind(console); echo(321)`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, this works. But I can't get `this` inside `__op__` work as a link to `x` when `x` isn't bound to anything.

Comment: If you can endure x being not a real function, i.e. you cannot call `x.call()`, `x.apply()` and `x.bind()`, you can definitely skip the `prop.__proto__ = inst.__proto__` statement. If you indeed just need `bind`, you can also write `inst.bind = f.bind`. Without multiple inheritance, these are all the tools you have.

Comment: Yes, but copying `Function` properties one by one seemed as a bad idea as well =) I'd like `x` to have a valid prototype, because who knows what library checks prototypes to ensure argument to be a function.

Comment: When `x` isn't bound to anything, the context should be the global object (`window` in a browser and `global` in nodejs), but not `x` itself. Try run this `!function () { console.log(this); }();` and `x.__op__ = function () { console.log(this); }; x()`. They yield the same result: `window`.

Comment: I know that. That is a behaviour modification I wanted.

Comment: What a strange desire 8-). Since there is no way to distinguish whether a function is called without a context, or it is (really!) called with `window` as a context. This is the best you can achieve: `return inst.__op__.apply(this === window ? inst : this, arguments)`.

Comment: That just looks terrible... but why not?

Comment: That's what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/98n8y4d4/ . Both my requirements met and problems solved, with a little exception: `x` cannot be explicitly bound to window if created with non-empty `prop` param. I can live with that, who binds to window after all?

Comment: I finally see how you are going to use it! There is probably no way for you to avoid copying the properties over from `prop` to `inst` if you really need them.